# R: Custom axis using at = null and alternative labels

Tags: r

I am looking for a way to replace my default y axis with custom values while using the automatic position computation (at = NULL) and specifying alternative labels.

Example image: http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160406/l4u6gp2w.png

The used data frame is populated with a nano second timestamp (which do not represent a real point in time but keep track of the elapsed time between each entry), a value, and the real timestamp. The nanosecond timestamp needs to be used to plot the graph but I would like to populate the y axis labels using the real date time.

```
plot(x = nsJavaTime,y=Median, xaxt='n')
axis(side=1,at=NULL, labels=format(TimestampLocal, '%b-%y'))
```

The documentation already says that this combination is impossible. But what is the correct way to do it?

> **at**     the points at which tick-marks are to be drawn. Non-finite
>   (infinite, NaN or NA) values are omitted. By default (when NULL)
>   tick mark locations are computed, see ‘Details’ below.
>
> **labels**     this can either be a logical value specifying whether
>   (numerical) annotations are to be made at the tickmarks, or a
>   character or expression vector of labels to be placed at the
>   tickpoints. (Other objects are coerced by as.graphicsAnnot.) If this
>   is not logical, at should also be supplied and of the same length. If
>   labels is of length zero after coercion, it has the same effect as
>   supplying TRUE.

As much as I understand the labels parameter is used to supply an alternative source for the labels but needs a fixed size related to the actual amount of labels being used later on.
The data I use will vary greatly so I can not find suited values for at but rather want to use the default NULL values which computes the positions automatically.

Comment: This looks like a complicated way to make the axis. Why not simply convert the nano timestamp into real timestamp and plot against that.

Comment: Because the nano time stamp isn't a real time stamp. It's just made up numbers which just keep track of the difference between the actual entries. Java's system.nano() "This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time."